# Internal App to retrieve leads / get informated via WebHook

Tags: facebook

The Meta API is pretty new for me and I'm not quite sure if I understood everything correctly. My use-case is quite simple:

I want to access my customer's leads (created by their lead ads) and set up a webhook for new leads. Since this only is an internal app, I do not want to review my app / set it public etc..

Is this possible with the API? And if so, does my customer need to create a developer account so I can add them to my application? There are four roles: Admin, Dev, Tester, Analytics. Since none of them is called "User" it seems like I might abuse this function?

Comment: Theoretically, this is allowed, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release: _"If your app will only be used by people who have a role on the app itself you do not need to complete any of these processes because your app is already available to these users."_ There are some endpoints/ some functionalities, that do not work with "real" data though, when the app is in test mode - you'd have to check, if everything works as expected.

Comment: And your customers will have to register their account as a developer with Facebook first, otherwise you will not be able to add them to any of your app roles.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just post this as an answer so I can mark it as solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, this is allowed, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release:

> If your app will only be used by people who have a role on the app itself you do not need to complete any of these processes because your app is already available to these users.

There are some endpoints/ some functionalities, that do not work with "real" data though, when the app is in test mode - you'd have to check, if everything works as expected.

And your customers will have to register their account as a developer with Facebook first, otherwise you will not be able to add them to any of your app roles.